# Editing of vector layer programmatically with QGIS

Tags: qgis, python, editing, pyqgis

I'm trying to edit vector layer using Python console and have couple of questions. Why this approach doesn't work and I have to use `canvas.refresh`? If I will use this code not in python console but in script file should I also use `canvas.refresh`?

```
# This approach doesn't work
layer = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()
layer.startEditing()
layer.moveVertex(7402946,6186167,0,0)

# This one works fine
canvas = qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas()
layer = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()
layer.startEditing()
canvas.refresh()
layer.moveVertex(7402946,6186167,0,0)
```

What is the right way to perform such operation? I've found that I can make the same things using `QgsVectorLayerEditUtils`:

```
layer.startEditing()
eu = QgsVectorLayerEditUtils(layer)
canvas.refresh()
eu.moveVertex(7402946,6186167,0,0)
```

Comment: What do you mean by `# This approach doesn't work`?

Comment: I mean that `moveVertex` returns `False` and there are no visible changes after canvas refreshing.

Comment: It's because the vertex markers are not draw until a canvas refresh which is what `moveVertex` is doing.  The correct way to move a node is to edit the geometry.

Comment: @Nathan W, sounds like an answer!